# Click on a link which is in the 2nd table on the page using Selenium's webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have 2 tables on a page.  Both tables contain a link called Payment:

```
<table class='topMenu' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr class='null'>
    <td>
      <a class='logoClient' href="http://www.txtag.org" target="_blank">
        <img class='imgNoBorder' src='/Violation/Images/logos/logo-client.gif' />
      </a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='S' class="iconSearchLink" onfocus="javascript:nav('login/secure/loadSearch.action?validate=n&cmd=clearsearch&', 'Search-act')">
        <u>S</u>earch</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='E' class="iconEnrollLink" onfocus="javascript:nav('enroll.do?cmd=goto&type=reg&', 'Enrollment-reg')">
        <u>E</u>nroll</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='C' class="iconContactLink" onfocus="javascript:navCheckAcct('searchNoteHistory.do', 'Contact-not')">
        <u>C</u>ontact</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='H' class="iconHistoryActive" onfocus="javascript:navCheckAcct('sysTran.do?cmd=gotoRefSch&updateDate=07-12-12', 'History-act')">
        <u>H</u>istory</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='P' class="iconPaymentLink" onfocus="javascript:navCheckAcct('searchPaymentAccount.do','Payment-pay')">
        <u>P</u>ayment</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='A' class="iconAccountLink" onfocus="javascript:navCheckAcct('account.do','Account-inf')">
        <u>A</u>ccount</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='I' class="iconInventoryLink" onfocus="javascript:nav('inventoryReconcile.do?cmd=goto&cancel=yes','Inventory-rec')">
        <u>I</u>nventory</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='M' class="iconImgProcLink" onfocus="javascript:nav('supervisorReview.do?cmd=goto', '')">I<u>m</u>age</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" class="iconReportDisabled">
        <u>R</u>eports</a>
    </td>
    <td class='iconBox'>
      <a href="#" accesskey='L' class="iconLogoutLink" onfocus="javascript:nav('logout.do?cmd=logout', '')">
        <u>L</u>og Out</a>
    </td>
    <td class='logoCompanyImage200'>
      <img class='imgNoBorder' src='/Violation/Images/logos/logo-company.gif' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class='subMenu' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul class="lavaLampWithImage" id="1">
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('gotoTollMit.do', 'History-tol')">Tag Tolls</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('gotoMitigation.do', 'History-vio')">Image Tolls</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:nav('paymentHistory.do?cmd=feeHistory', 'History-fee')">Fees</a>
        </li>
        <li class="current"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('sysTran.do?cmd=goto', 'History-act')">Activity</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('history.do?cmd=status&', 'History-sta')">Status</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('history.do?cmd=veh&', 'History-veh')">Vehicle</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('history.do?cmd=tag&', 'History-tag')">Transponder</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('history.do?cmd=demo&', 'History-dem')">Personal Info</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('history.do?cmd=pay&', 'History-pay')">Payment</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('history.do?cmd=stmt&', 'History-stm')">Statement</a>
        </li>
        <li class="doesnotexist"/>
        <a style="cursor: hand; " onClick="javascript:navCheckAcct('bankruptcy.do?cmd=bankruptcy', 'History-ban')">Bankruptcy</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'm attempting to click on the link Payment which is in the 2nd table called `subMenu` using the below code:

```
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class = 'subMenu']/tr[td[//a[contains(text(), 'Payment')]]]")).click();
```

When utilizing the above code, the program no longer throws and exception stating that the element cannot be found; however, the link is not clicked upon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your xpath is that it is returning the tr element. I assume you want the link element.

Try using the xpath:

```
//table[@class = 'subMenu']//a[contains(text(), 'Payment')]
```

Comment: Yes, but the above script still will not click on the desire link.

Comment: Actually by setting the WebElement and then clicking doing the click allowed both to function.                            WebElement cellValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class = '" + findBy + "']//a[contains(text(), '" + elem + "')]"));  
            cellValue.click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class = '" + findBy + "']//a[contains(text(), '" + elem + "')]")).click();